# How to read files and avoid coercing to unicode error in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, io, directory

Im reading two files (`trainfile, testfile`), then i would like to vecrize them with `word_vectorizer`, the problem is that maybe im not reading the files in the right way this is what i tried:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
import codecs

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import os, sys


with open('/Users/user/Desktop/train.txt', 'r') as trainfile:
    contenido_del_trainfile= trainfile.read()
    print contenido_del_trainfile

with open('/Users/user/Desktop/test.txt', 'r') as testfile:
    contenido_del_testfile= testfile.read()
    print contenido_del_testfile


print "\nThis is the training corpus:\n", contenido_del_trainfile
print "\nThis is the test corpus:\n", contenido_del_testfile



train = []

word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word')

trainset = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(codecs.open(trainfile,'r','utf8'))
print word_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

Here is the output:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

How can i read the files in the right way in order to print something like this:

```
[u'word',... ,u'word']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`codecs.open` asserts, that you provide a path to file, not a file itself.

So, instead of

```
trainset = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(codecs.open(trainfile,'r','utf8'))
```

Do

```
trainset = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(codecs.open('/Users/user/Desktop/train.txt','r','utf8'))
```